# Kendo Grid rowTemplate JS function

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

In a single javascript file I have the following kendo grid option.

```
var relatedJobsGridOptions = ko.observable({});

//I am seeing message, javascript function is never used :(
function getName(name) {
  return name;
}

relatedJobsGridOptions({
  columns: [
    { field: 'name', title: 'Customer Name ', width: '160px' },
  ],
  dataSource: OccData,
  rowTemplate: (
    '<tr style="background-color: rgb(246,246,246)" data-uid="#= uid #">' +
      '<td>#=getName(name)# </td>' +
    '</tr>'      
  ),          
  overflow: false
});
```

How I can call the javascript function inside this rowTemplate?

I have referred few telerik forums, but as for as I searched none is matching my condition (My poor research :( I am completely got stuck here..)
Any suggestion would be helpful to me.

Comment: Try `<#= getName(name) #>`

Answer (score 1):

Just use a string interpolation:

```js
function getName (name) {
  return `<strong>${name}</strong>`
} 

const rowTemplate = `
  <tr style="background-color: rgb(246,246,246)" data-uid="#= uid #">
    <td>#= ${ getName('some name') } #</td>
  </tr>   
`.trim()

console.log(rowTemplate);
```

Comment: Still not able to detect the function :(

Comment: please, create a code snippet, that demonstrates your problem.